# FontAwesome SVG + JS with pseudo-elements performance issue on Select2

Tags: font-awesome, jquery-select2

I'm actually using the FontAwesome 5 package, using the SVG+JS implementation with the "data-search-pseudo-elements" option.

I'm in a context where I use a "Select2" plug-in to display a `<select>` element, which is containing nearly 600 options (for a timezone selection). But when I try to open the select to choose an option, it takes a very very long time to open (which doesn't occur when using the CSS framework, or when pseudo-elements are disabled)!

A little look in browser performances panel seems to show that it's the FontAwesome script which is responsible of this, while there is no pseudo-element in the elements generated by Select2.

Is there any way to improve FontAwesome performance, or to avoid its activation for some HTML elements?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have `data-search-pseudo-elements` enabled, Font Awesome will scan the DOM when changes are made, looking for any pseudo-elements that represent icons that should be converted into `<svg>` elements.

Unfortunately, a scenario like you've described is the Achilles heel of this feature. Scanning the DOM for all possible pseudo-elements can be slow when there are many DOM elements. And the Mutation Observer causes re-scans to occur whenever the DOM changes--which is what sounds like is happening when you open that select control.

So it's probably best to avoid SVG/JS with pseudo-elements in a situation like this.

While I would not recommend putting more effort into trying a work around, if you're up against a wall and for some reason have a requirement to continue using SVG/JS *and* pseudo-elements together like this, then here are two possibilities:

1. If you don't need the MutationObserver to watch for changes, then you could disable it altogether using the [Configuration](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/setup/configuration) API. For example, add `data-observe-mutations="false"` to your `<script>` tag.
2. If you do need the MutationObserver to watch for changes elsewhere in the DOM, but not on this select control, then after disabling the MutationObserver on load (using the above), you could kick it off programmatically on a smaller region of the DOM using the [`dom.watch()` API](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/methods/dom-watch) with a `observeMutationsRoot` parameter that is more narrowly scoped. By default, the MutationObserver, when enabled, scans everything under a root of `document.body`, but this is a way that you can make it work on a smaller region of the DOM.

If you have a requirement to support pseudo-elements, and especially if you need to support that in a DOM with many elements, and especially especially if the DOM is changing a lot, it's almost certainly going to be best for you to use the CSS/Webfont technology.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Actually there is only one form where I use such a select element with so many entries, and it's not used very frequently so I'm going to keep it as it is...